# Zend Json render data into views

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

Hi i have an Zend Framework apps, the following code are `popularAction` controller

```
public function popularAction()
    {
        $type = $this->_getParam('ref',1);
        if($type == 'reviews'){
        $businessReviewMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_BusinessReviewsMapper();
        $result = $businessReviewMapper->getTotalVote();

        $rotd = $businessReviewMapper->getROTD($result['review_id']);
        $rotd[0]['u_img'] = $this->view->getLoginUserImage($rotd[0]['social_id'],$rotd[0]['login_type'],null,null,square);
        $rotd[0]['rating'] = $this->view->getRatingImg($rotd[0]['rating']);
        $rotd[0]['business_name_url'] = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i","-", $rotd[0]['business_name']);            
        $this->render('reviews');
        $this->_helper->json($rotd);



        } elseif($type == 'openings') {
            $this->view->text = "New Openings";

        } else {
            $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index', 'default');
        }

    }
```

When a user browse to `http://localhost/business/popular?ref=reviews` the above controller code would render reviews.phtml template. Now inside the template itself there is ajax request for a data as follow:

```
function getPopular()
{
    var count=1;
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?=$this->baseUrl('business/popular?ref=reviews')?>",
        data:{'count':count},
        dataType:"json"
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){
            alert('ok')
        }
    });
```

unfortunately the `$this->_helper->json($rotd);` doesn't pass data to the reviews.phtml,but display json data which is returned by zend db model, where i might be wrong?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your Goal is to, to send JSON instead of the .phtml File on an Ajax Request, try to implement this:

```
  if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if ($this->getRequest()-isPost()) {
            $this->_helper->json($rotd);
        }
    }
```

This part checks if the request is, lets call it: ajax based..